# Check if php script is being run from another script via cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a `php` script that runs via cron at 2am every morning.  It runs some code in another script and this other script is also publicly available.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
if (SCRIPT_RUN_FROM CRON) {
   //code here
}
```

How would I do this?

The code within the block `//code here` I only want to run from the cron script.  Its a caching feature which is causing some problems so I only want it being run once from the cron and not when anyone visits the page.

Comment: The `cron` job could pass a value on the command line, which the script sets to a variable.  This condition could then check for the value in that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is running via CRON, it's running from cli... so try the following:

```
if(php_sapi_name() === "cli") {
    //running from CRON, do stuff
}
```